# Which parts of the HTML code should I check to correct this JS error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

When I try to make one div fade out, it won't let me and tells me that the other divs are fading out. I'm trying to select a specific div, which it won't let me. What lines, in each of these three files do I need to check to correct my error?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('#blue').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vanishing Act</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <br/><button>Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS code, in case it helps:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F38630;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#blue {
    background-color: #A7DBD8;
}
```

What I'm trying to do, again, is select *just the blue ID* in JS, in the JQ library. So, which lines of code do I have to look at and where's the problem?

Comment: can you post a fiddle that recreates the issue? It's hard to give you an answer with out seeing the HTML

Comment: *Also, does anyone notice the similarities between syntax in JQ and JS?* - that might be because jQuery is nothing but a JavaScript library!

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple divs with that ID.

Comment: A fiddle? What's a fiddle? You mean edit it to include all of the code? I don't know if that's allowed on this site. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @user3695903 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a place where you can post your code for people to check out

Comment: `tells me that the other divs are fading out` ... what tells you and how?

Answer (score 0):

Follow up what you and Bram said, check these possibilities:

1. You have multiple divs with id "blue"
2. You target the wrong div
3. Update your browser and check it in several browser.

I think, it is best to re-check your HTML code.